# Is it possible to setup Nest.js HTTP module to use Promises instead of Observables globally?

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I can't seem to find a way to setup [Nest.js HTTP module](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module) to use promises instead of observabables globally.

Seems that you can only pass a config object for the Axios instance but there are no options for the service itself.

Right now I'm wrapping every single request with `lastValueFrom()` to get a `Promise` instead of an `Observable`.

Comment: Why do you think, this is possible to configure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@nestjs/axios` doesn't have any promise-based interface for `axios`. If you want to use promises, try this another lib instead: https://github.com/benhason1/nestjs-http-promise

More on this: https://github.com/nestjs/axios/issues/271